# Micrometer publish to JMX in non-SpringBoot-Project

Tags: jmx, micrometer

It seems like there is a lot of magic going on in Micrometer and SpringBoot to publish to the chosen monitoring system.

Is it possible to publish the information I gather with Micrometer to JMX in a non-SpringBoot application?

I added the dependency

```
implementation 'io.micrometer:micrometer-registry-jmx:latest.release'
```

and I added a Timer like that

```
Timer timer =
      Timer.builder("name")
          .publishPercentiles(0, 0.5, 0.75, 0.95)
          .register(Metrics.globalRegistry);
```

but now I need to publish that data to JMX to be able to see that data in the JConsole. I searched the internet but as I am pretty new to Micrometer and JMX, I am not able to find anything that helps me solve that problem yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what magic are you referring to, Spring Boot will auto-configure the `MeterRegistry` instances for you.

If you want to use the `JmxMeterRegistry`, you need to create an instance of it, see: [docs](https://micrometer.io/docs/registry/jmx) and [samples](https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/micrometer/blob/15a2247785d8cb4638717431dc78041e3c66c107/samples/micrometer-samples-core/src/main/java/io/micrometer/core/samples/utils/SampleRegistries.java#L300-L313).

Then you can use it:

```java
MeterRegistry registry = new JmxMeterRegistry(...);
Timer timer = Timer.builder("test").register(registry);
```

If you don't want to inject your `MeterRegistry` everywhere, you can use the global registry, [see the docs](https://micrometer.io/docs/concepts#_registry):

```java
MeterRegistry registry = new JmxMeterRegistry(...);
Metrics.addRegistry(registry);
```

Though recommend injecting your `MeterRegistry` especially if you are using any dependency injection solution.

Comment: Perfect, I didn't think that it was that easy. I thought Spring would perform more Magic to publish that data. Thank you!